# Send parameters to injected mock beans

Tags: spring, mocking, testng, parameter-passing

Doing a component test with testNG I need to mock a service that gets some external data.

To do this I configure the mock in the file spring-test-config.xml like this:

```
<beans xmlns=...>
    <context:component-scan base-package="..." />

    <bean id="dataRetrieverBean" class="org.my.project.DataRetrieverBeanMock" scope="prototype"/>
</beans>
```

And then I reference this config file in my test class like this:

```
@Test()
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring-test-config.xml" })
public class MyNGTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    [...]
}
```

The mock always return "Hello world" when the component that I want to test calls "getStringResponse()" on it:

```
public class DataRetrieverBeanMock implements Response {

  @Override
  public String getStringResponse() {
    return "Hello world";
  }
}
```

Till here everything works as expected!

Now to test the component under different conditions I need that the String returned by DataRetrieverBeanMock (currently hardcoded with "Hello world") changes for each test case, for example the first test would test the component when the response is "success", the second when the response is "error 109" and so on.
How can I define the string to be returned inside the test case and pass it to the mock bean?